# Informatica: How to filter a table based on aggregation result of another table?

Tags: filter, aggregation, informatica

In Informatica, how to filter a table based on the aggregation result of another table?

Given the following 2 tables:

Table_1:
SomeText VARCHAR,
SomeDate DATE

Table_2:
SomeDate_2 DATE,
OutputDate_2 DATE

and the following aggregation (into output port "MinDate") of Table_2:

SELECT MIN(OutputDate_2) AS MinDate
FROM Table_2
WHERE SomeDate_2 BETWEEN 01/01/2023 AND 02/01/2023

how can Table_1 be filtered on SomeDate >= MinDate?

If I can add a port/column in Table_1's source qualifier with MinDate, I can use that to filter Table_1. But not sure if that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have another `Source Qualifier`, do a `Full Outer Join` and use a `Filter Transformation`.

```
Src1-SQ1---Jnr--Flt--Tgt
          /
Src2-SQ2-/
```

In such case you need to pay attention to the way you join, as it might produce a lot of duplicated rows if not done carefully.

Another option is single `Source Qualifier` with two `Source Transformations` connected and a `SQL Override`. This is pretty much the same thing you did, but it will clearly indicate the use of both sources at the first glance at the mapping.

```
Src1-SQ1---Jnr--Flt--Tgt
     /
Src2/
```

Comment: Thank you @Maciejg. Unfortunately, I'm still very new at Informatica and have been unsuccessful so far with my attempts at your 2 suggestions.

With the first suggestion, by "another Source Qualifier", my two tables already have their own Source Qualifiers, so did you mean a third SQ?

Comment: With the second suggestion, "single Source Qualifier with two Source Transformations", I understand use just one SQ shared by the two tables. But I as yet do not know what "Source Transformations" are. I think I understand it means I can do some transformation on the source table (for example, do aggregation on the second table) before linking it with the SQ.

Thank you and I will continue looking into your suggestions.

Comment: I haven't done it in Informatica yet but I think I got it now. For the first scenario, in the second table's SQ, I can do a SQL Query to do the aggregation. For the second scenario, I can at least show the two tables visually then drop the entire SQL Query in the shared SQ. Brilliant -- thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just used Sql Query in the source qualifier.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).